# R: fitting power law curve to data (starting value for c)

Tags: r

I have some data to which I'm trying to fit power law curve using:

```
z <- nls(y ~ a*x^b+c, start = list(a=1, b=1))
```

However I keep getting the following error message:

> Error in a * x^b + c : non-numeric argument to binary operator

(the shorter version i.e. `y ~ a*x^b+c` works fine but I need the free term `c`).

Any ideas ?

Comment: why don't you have `c` in your list of starting values?

Comment: As warned in the answer -- **never** use `c` , or `T` or `F` for that matter, as a variable name, for reasons which should be obvious.  Some other single-letter variable names to avoid: `t` and`q` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've not specified `c` in your start, so R tries to get it from the workspace. If there's no `c` there it ends up getting the `c` function, in all likelihood. So its trying to add something to the `c` function, and throwing up:

```
> z <- nls(y ~ a*x^b+c, start = list(a=1, b=1))
Error in a * x^b + c : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The "binary operator" here is `+` and the "non-numeric argument" is the `c` function.

If you want to fit `c`:

```
> z <- nls(y ~ a*x^b+c, start = list(a=1, b=1, c=1))
> z
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a * x^b + c
   data: parent.frame()
    a     b     c 
1.647 1.575 2.596 
 residual sum-of-squares: 9.07

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.503e-07
```

If you want to fix `c`, define it and then leave it out:

```
> c=2
> z <- nls(y ~ a*x^b+c, start = list(a=1, b=1))
> z
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a * x^b + c
   data: parent.frame()
    a     b 
1.802 1.539 
 residual sum-of-squares: 9.42

Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.899e-08
```

Comment: omg, I forgot 'c'... I added 'c' but now I get:

Error in nls(y ~ a * x^b + c, start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1, c = 0.1)) : 
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562

Also, I tried using package 'nls2' with 'brute-force' algorithm and it worked !
'nls2' performs parameter estimation prior to fitting; looks good now...
Btw, I can't believe how quickly you people reply to posts :) Thnx !!!

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include a starting value for c?

Comment: if your data doesn't fit that equation well, or if your initial parameters are way off, you might get errors like that. We can't reproduce that without your data, most likely.